# Iterate through list using it as a search in a 2d array

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I have list that needs to be translated into a multidimensional array. Then I want to search several other multidimensional arrays for the values in the list and put them into a new multidimensional array that contains all of the data. The arrays are structured as follows and are jagged arrays.

```
userArray = [StudentID, Password, Username, TutorGroup, YearGroup, AccountType]
MeetRequests = [StudentID, Request, Urgent]
feelingsArray = [StudentID, Tiredness, Workload, Stress]
```

I require all values from each list except for the Username and password from userArray and StudentID from MeetRequests and feelingsArray.
The list that I mentioned earlier contains all of the StudentIDs. I want to iterate through the list then search the three arrays above for the corresponding StudentArray. However I am being given an error with the following code:

```
    //Defines all the stuff
        private Rect windowRect = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);
public Vector2 scrollPosition = Vector2.zero;
private int BSpace;
public string[,] SortedStudentArray;
private int j;
private string[][] MeetRequests;
private string[] temp;
private System.Collections.Generic.List<string> H_Priority = new List<string>();
private System.Collections.Generic.List<string> M_Priority = new List<string>();
private System.Collections.Generic.List<string> L_Priority = new List<string>();
private System.Collections.Generic.List<string> FullList = new List<string>();
private string[] Holding = new string[5];
private string[] SearchTerms;

    //This is where the main body of code is

        string[][] feelingsArray = GetComponent<Userdata>().CallFeelings();

    //Info array about each user
    string[,] SortedStudentArray = new string[FullList.Count, 11];


    //for each item in FullList
    for (int y = 0; y < FullList.Count; y++)
    {
        //Find corresponding Student Info in userArray
        Holding = Array.BinarySearch(Userdata.userArray, FullList<y>);
        Array.Copy(Holding, 0, SortedStudentArray[y], 0, 5);
        Holding = Array.BinarySearch(MeetRequests, FullList<y>);
        Array.Copy(Holding, 1, SortedStudentArray[y], 6, 2);
        Holding = Array.BinarySearch(feelingsArray, FullList<y>);
        Array.Copy(Holding, 1, SortedStudentArray[y], 8, 3);
    }

    return SortedStudentArray;
```

So It would be appreciated if I could be given some direction on how to search the other arrays as Array.Copy, from what I can tell, doesn't work with multidimensional arrays and there is also a type error with the List.

The errors I am getting are:

```
Assets/Scripts/Staff/MeetingRequestViewer.cs(144,9): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
Assets/Scripts/Staff/MeetingRequestViewer.cs(166,29): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to `string[]'
Assets/Scripts/Staff/MeetingRequestViewer.cs(168,29): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to `string[]'
Assets/Scripts/Staff/MeetingRequestViewer.cs(170,29): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to `string[]'
Assets/Scripts/Staff/MeetingRequestViewer.cs(20,70): error CS0104: `List' is an ambiguous reference between `Boo.Lang.List<T>' and `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'
Assets/Scripts/Staff/MeetingRequestViewer.cs(20,66): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `Boo.Lang.List<string>' to `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'
Assets/Scripts/Staff/MeetingRequestViewer.cs(21,70): error CS0104: `List' is an ambiguous reference between `Boo.Lang.List<T>' and `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'
Assets/Scripts/Staff/MeetingRequestViewer.cs(21,66): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `Boo.Lang.List<string>' to `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'
Assets/Scripts/Staff/MeetingRequestViewer.cs(22,70): error CS0104: `List' is an ambiguous reference between `Boo.Lang.List<T>' and `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'
Assets/Scripts/Staff/MeetingRequestViewer.cs(22,66): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `Boo.Lang.List<string>' to `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'
Assets/Scripts/Staff/MeetingRequestViewer.cs(23,68): error CS0104: `List' is an ambiguous reference between `Boo.Lang.List<T>' and `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'
```

Assets/Scripts/Staff/MeetingRequestViewer.cs(23,64): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `Boo.Lang.List<string>' to`System.Collections.Generic.List'

Comment: Can you talk us through why `userArray` is a multi-dimensional array vs, say a `List<User>`?

Comment: The is a new user on each row in the array, I was not sure how to implement a list of arrays so I decided to use the concept of what I know, plus it has something to do with the way I am indexing elsewhere in another script @mjwills

Comment: As far as I can see, all your "arrays" here should simply each be their own class, with class properties instead of your fixed-index array values. That would simplify things a whole lot.

Comment: @Nyerguds I did realise this however this is the first time I've have used OOP and a list of classes was a bit intimidating

Comment: That's exactly what `List<T>` is _for_ though.

Comment: okay, I haven't done it that way so is there a way that will work for how I have done it?

Comment: What is `FullList`? Exactly what error are you getting, and exactly where are you getting it? And, uh, what is `FullList<y>` supposed to mean? That doesn't look like c# syntax at all. `<>` should surround a type, not an index...

Comment: 'FullList' is a list of StudentIDs, which I then want to find in the other arrays. I thought that 'FullList<y>' would index the list... and cycle through each value in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my issues, I used a `foreach` loop which allowed my to iterate through the FullList and then compared the variable to the element in `userData.userArray[y][0]`. The to transfer the data I used a nested for loop to cycle through the elements in `userData.userArray` and transfer them to `SortedStudentArray`

```
 string[,] SortedStudentArray = new string[FullList.Count, 11];

    //Line Counter
    int SSAPos = 0;

    // For every element in FullList
    foreach (var item in FullList)
    {
        //For each user in userArray
        for (int y = 0; y < Userdata.userArray.Length; y++)
        {
            if (Userdata.userArray[y][0] == item)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < Userdata.userArray[y].Length; n++)
                {
                    SortedStudentArray[SSAPos, n] = Userdata.userArray[y][n];
                }
                SSAPos +=1; 
                break;
            }
        }
```